# PHP redirect after form processing

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've been staring at code too long however when I used a simple script to save a form with:

```
endif;
header('Location: http:/mysite.com/evo/codesaveindex.php');
?>
```

at the end the page redirected back to itself just fine, however now I have a longer script here I can't quite figure out where or how to code my redirect:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $directory = 'users/'.$_SESSION['username'].'/';
  //here you can even check if user selected 'Delete' option:
  if($_POST['Action'] == "DELETE"){
      $file_to_delete = $_POST['CodeList'];
      if(unlink($directory.'/'.$file_to_delete))
         echo $file_to_delete." deleted.";
      else
         echo "Error deleting file ".$file_to_delete;
  }
   if($_POST['Action'] == "SAVE"){
     //  If a session already exists, this doesn't have any effect.
session_start();
//  Sets the current directory to the directory this script is running in
chdir(dirname(__FILE__));
//  Breakpoint
if( empty($_SESSION['username']) || $_SESSION['username'] == '' ) echo 'There is no session username';
if( empty($_POST['CodeDescription']) || $_POST['CodeDescription'] == '' ) echo 'There is no POST desired filename';
//  This is assuming we are working from the current directory that is running this PHP file.
$USER_DIRECTORY = 'users/'.$_SESSION['username'];
//  Makes the directory if it doesn't exist
if(!is_dir($USER_DIRECTORY)):
    mkdir($USER_DIRECTORY);
endif;
//  Put together the full path of the file we want to create
$FILENAME = $USER_DIRECTORY.'/'.$_POST['CodeDescription'].'.txt';
if( !is_file( $FILENAME ) ):
    // Open the text file, write the contents, and close it.
    file_put_contents($FILENAME, $_POST['Code']);   
   endif;
   }
  ?>
```

Comment: When do you want it to redirect?

Comment: sorry should have clarified. After either option, after saving and after deleting depending on which Action they're choosing.

Comment: As has already been pointed out, you have several branches of code which generate text output, and that will interfere with creating a redirect header. But what do you want to do about those messages? Should the page display an error or, for a successful deletion, the success message, or should it always redirect?

Comment: I wasn't worried so much about a success message though I might figure out how to work that in, I wanted it to always redirect on a successful deletion or save depending on which button they hit and if not echo an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

may be you should use querystring variable while redirecting.

```
if($_POST['Action'] == "DELETE") {
    $file_to_delete = $_POST['CodeList'];
    if(unlink($directory.'/'.$file_to_delete)) {
        header('Location: http:/mysite.com/evo/codesaveindex.php?deleted=1&file='.$file_to_delete);
    } else {
        header('Location: http:/mysite.com/evo/codesaveindex.php?deleted=0&              file='.$file_to_delete);
    }
}
```

In codesaveindex.php:

```
if(isset($_GET['deleted'])&& $_GET['deleted']==1) {
    echo $file_to_delete." deleted.";
} elseif(isset($_GET['deleted'])&& $_GET['deleted']==0) {
    echo "Error deleting file ".$file_to_delete; 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much rsb for your help. This worked. The only thing is that it shows Location: myaddresshere/evo/codesaveindex.php?deleted=1&file=$file_to_delete in the address bar after successful delete rather then the name of the file after delete=1&, not sure if thats supposed to actually show the file name instead.

Comment: Well I have edited rsb's code due to some syntax error. And it is now finally updated. You can see the results. (DON'T FORGET TO PICK THE SOLUTION IF IT WORKS)

Comment: I was back and forth working on editing my code and forgot to checkmark the solution. Thank you again rsb and for helping on the syntax AkiEru

Comment: Actually now im in python environment so now quite unfamiliar with php syntax & im struggling to format my code while answering ,thanks for formatting my code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't redirect if the page after html has been outputted.
You need to either use output buffering or redirect using javascript,
or organise it so that the redirect happens before the html is shown.

Comment: thank you jojojohn I am looking up and reading on trying to figure out the best and easiest solution to do this.

Comment: Looking up and reading about output buffers, I've tried numerous examples of starting the buffer and attempting to flush it but cannot seem to get it to work.

Comment: How about header()? I think it should count as a "Redirecting" function.

Comment: You are correct AkiEru and I appreciate the assist the problem I was having was how to write it and realizing where my output was so I could fix it.

Answer (score 0):

i have a class written for such thing, should be very easy to use [class.route.php](http://www.littleblogthing.com/snippets/php-classes/route-php-redirects-and-http-status-class)
simply do this where you want to redirect: route::redirect('page', http_status);

Comment: I don't know if 'redirect' might have been the wrong word, I basically just want the page to refresh and come back to the same page after the script is ran.

Comment: I may just not know where to write it but I cannot seem to get it to work.